# Python ignoring the escape sequence character '\' inside print statements for a string?

Tags: python

So in the IDLE Python IDE I'm using this statement

```
print ("Hello, \ World!")
```

and the output I get is:

> Hello, \ World!

But AFAIK, shouldn't the backslash not be printed? The only time it should be printed is when there is another backslash in front of it right? Then, why is it printing the backslash in the output?

Answer (score 3):

`\`  is an invalid escape sequence, so it's interpreted as-is. Same goes with anything that's [not documented](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-and-bytes-literals) to be an escape sequence.

Comment: Thank you! I got confused because of a misprint in the book I'm using to learn Python. There they mention how '\' can be used to escape a line break but in the example code provided they typed everything out in the same line (i.e 'print ("Hello, \ World!)' instead of the 'World!' part being in the next line. I tried the example code as is and it printed the backslash in the output so that confused me. Thanks again!